# Creating a "Split Button"

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

In CRM 2011 I want to create a new ribbon button that includes a drop down of different actions, such as what you get for running a report or importing data.

A bit of research seems to suggest that these are called Split Buttons, but there doesn't seem to be any information on actually how to create them.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to make these is with the Ribbon Workfbench, its an excellent tool I cant recommend enough.

[Ribbon Workbench](http://www.develop1.net/public/page/Ribbon-Workbench-for-Dynamics-CRM-2011.aspx)

The site also includes tutorials which explain how to create these various buttons.

Comment: This looks to be a very useful tool, managed to create a split button in a matter of minutes! Thanks for your help